# Two EC2 in same VPC and SUBNET but one can connect internet and other not , why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-vpc

I have Two EC2 instances X & Y in same VPC and SUBNET. Instance X has INBOUND for SSH  & HTTP ports open to **Anywhere**.
Instance B has SSH port open to it's **VPC's CIDR range only**.
I can SSH in instance X and run yum updates from GITBASH successfully. My intention is to connect to instance Y through SSH from X and install mysql on Y since its SSH port is not open from anywhere.
I can connect to Y from X by SSH successfully, but it fails to install mysql on Y. It gives error as it cannot connect to Internet:
" Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://amazonlinux.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2/core/latest/x86_64/mirror.list error was
12: Timeout on ......."

Can someone please advise why Instance Y is not able to connect to internet via X  as both are on same VPC, SUBNET please ?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Does Y have public IP address? What are its outbound security group rules? Only yum does not work? What about pinging google.com or trying any other internet activity?

Comment: Y has private IP, no public IP and its outbound is "All-All - 0.0.0.0/0". Its inbound is "port:22 - defaultSECgroup . X has outbound  "All- All -0.0.0.0/0" and its inbound is "port:80 -All"  "port:22 -All" "Port:22 - defaultSECgroup". Non of the internet activity works in Y though I can SSH it from X to Y.

Comment: @Marcin - this is **so** bad question. First, this is not SO - there is nothing programming about it. Second - OP clearly is very new to AWS troubleshooting. Asks about seemingly outbound problem and gives all the information about inbound settings. So, it is a very poor question even for Server Fault. Finally, instance Y or B - lack of clarity. But since OP is so new, and you are so patient (obviously, that's why you are 80K, and I am order of magnitude less) - let's give it a try. :)

Comment: @Felix Hi. You are right, its not a perfect question, but I can roughly guess what's happening. Its also more about architecture, then programming, and "Questions about programming and architecture are on topic." from `amazon-web-services` tag description. So I tried to help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your instance Y has no public IP even though it is in a public subnet, it will not have internet access. You need to **have public IP** for that to happen.

Alternatively, you have to create **private subnet** and place your Y instance there. Also, in public subnet you will need to setup **NAT gateway** so that the instance Y can access the internet through the NAT gateway. No public IP is required in this scenario for the instance Y.